# Experiencing delays in keystrokes for Visual Studio over RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Does anyone have a suggestion for tweaking the performance of VS2010 over RDP? I'm not even convinced it's an RDP issue, as VS is the only app that has lag between actions (sometimes several seconds for typing to even appear) - the only plugin I'm using is WholeTomato's Visual Assist.

I've tried the `/LARGEMEMORYAWARE` (or it was something along those lines), but that doesn't seem to have solved anything.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very deep article from Microsoft Blogs about [optimizing Visual Studio 2010 over RDP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jgoldb/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop). Also, take a look at the Microsoft Forums post with [many troubleshooting links](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/6ed6500d-33f7-4f0c-89fb-8d8442c7a229/extremely-slow-rdp-session-solved).

In my case, **RD can get very slow and laggy** on very fast optical connection. I think it happens when some apps leak GDI resources and Windows handles, and Visual Studio requires very many GDI objects. In such cases, **I just do log off, and log on.** And everything is smooth again.

Comment: My problem was specifically with VS Code, but it still worked. Just logging off and on again. Amazing. Figures, right? "Did you reboot?" fixes nearly everything.